# Convert week number to date

Tags: r, as.date

I have a data frame in R with the week of the year that I would like to convert to a date. I know I have to pick a year and a day of the week so I am fixing those values at 2014 and 1.  Converting this to a date seems simple:

```
as.Date(paste(2014,df$Week,1,sep=""),"%Y%U%u")
```

But this code only works if week is greater than 9. Week 1 - 9 returns NA. If I change the week to 01,02,03... it still returns NA.

Anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform Year/Week to date object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object-in-r)

Comment: Beware of the different conventions on how to count week-of-the-year. Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/3817004) for a discussion.

Comment: @Uwe I think it is better to post your answer here and close the other Q as a duplicate

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`as.Date` is calling the 1 to 9 as NA as it is expects two digits for the week number and can't properly parse it.

To fix it, add in some - to split things up:

```
as.Date(paste(2014, df$Week, 1, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")
```

Comment: r strips out the `0` in 01 in numeric data - see the output of `paste(2014,01,1,sep="")` - "201411". You could do `paste(2014,"01",1,sep="")` to make it character, but if your data is numeric that won't easily work.

Comment: Beware of the different conventions on how to count week-of-the-year. Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/3817004) for a discussion.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative solution is to use date arithmetic from the `lubridate` package:

```
lubridate::ymd( "2014-01-01" ) + lubridate::weeks( df$Week - 1 )
```

The `-1` is necessary because `2014-01-01` is already week 1. In other words, we want:

- `df$Week == 1` to map to `2014-01-01` (which is `ymd("2014-01-01") + weeks(1-1)`)
- `df$Week == 2` to map to `2014-01-08` (which is `ymd("2014-01-01") + weeks(2-1)`)
- and so on.

Comment: How would you generalize this to take into account the change of years?

Comment: Beware of the different conventions on how to count week-of-the-year. Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/3817004) for a discussion.

Comment: @Phil `ymd("2014-01-01") + weeks(df$Week - 1) + years(df$Year - 2014)`  (assuming that a `Year` variable is there).

Answer (score 6):

Another option with `lubridate`

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(paste(2014, df$Week, 1, sep="/"),'Y/W/w')
```

**W** - week number, **w** - weekday number, 0-6 (Sun-Sat)

Comment: I checked it, it works well. Could you tell what result you have?

Comment: `[1] NA Warning message: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.`

Comment: Locale setting may be the cause, if  'Mon' is not your abbreviation for Monday
You can use 1 for Monday and 'u' instead of 'a'
`lubridate::parse_date_time(paste(2014, 42, 1, sep="/"),'Y/W/u')`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to make sure that week numbers have two digits, which can be done using `stringr::str_pad()`, which will add a `pad="0"` to make sure there are `width=2` digits:

```r
year <- 2015
week <- 1
as.Date(paste(year, week, "1", sep=""), "%Y%U%u")
#> [1] NA
as.Date(paste(year, stringr::str_pad(week,width=2, pad="0"), "1", sep=""), "%Y%U%u")
#> [1] "2015-01-05"
as.Date(paste(year, week, "1", sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")
#> [1] "2015-01-05"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

```
It will be like using 2nd year = (week-52), 3rd year  = (week -104)...so on

for(i in 1:456548)
{
  if (train[i,2] > 0 & train[i,2] <53)
  {
    train["weekdate"] <- as.Date(paste(2016, train$week, 1, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")
  }
  if (train[i,2] > 52 & train[i,2] <105)
  {
    train["weekdate"] <- as.Date(paste(2017, (train$week-52), 1, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")
  }
  if (train[i,2] > 104 & train[i,2] <150)
  {
    train["weekdate"] <- as.Date(paste(2018, (train$week-104), 1, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")
  }

}
```