# Convert year and week column into month R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, dayofweek, week-number

I want to determine the month based on the year and the week number. This problem is unique because it's missing the day of week information needed in these examples [Transform year/week to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object), [Convert week number to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470414/convert-week-number-to-date).

```
year <- c("2017", "2017", "2018")
week <- c("37", "53", "01")
month <- lubridate::month(as.Date(paste0(year, "-", week), format = "%Y-%V"))

> month
[1] 9 9 9
```

For some reason this returns `9` for each element in my vector. September is the correct month for the first observation, but this cannot be the case for the remaining two.

Expected output:

```
> month
[1] 9 12 1
```

**Edit:** It turns out that this task is unlikely to be solved without knowing the day of week. I'll try to find a workaround to the year/date to avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470414/convert-week-number-to-date   or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object

Comment: I have already tried following these examples. They are using the `%U` week format instead of the `%V` format. When I use `%U` I get an `NA` when the week is `53`. When I use the `%V` format, each month  is `9`... These examples also have a 'day' or 'weekday' element that I am missing.

Comment: Ahhh good point... I'll have to figure something else out then.

Comment: Not precise, but might be good enough:  library(lubridate); library(magrittr); 
`paste(year, 1,1) %>% ymd %>% add(as.numeric(week) * 7) %>% month()`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
> year <- c(2017, 2017, 2018)
> week <- c(37, 53, 01)
> month <- lubridate::month(as.Date(paste0(year, "-", week, "-", 10), format = "%Y-%U-%u"))
> month
 [1] 9 NA 1
```

The reason you get **NA** here, because it will calculate months upto 52nd week.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using a `10` for the day of week?

Comment: You need to add a **date** as you'll have to specify Year-month-date format.
You can put any date ranging 1-30

Comment: Standard says it should be 1-7, but you can put any integer. This date part is simply ignored when you have **lubridate:month**