# How do I chronologically plot weeks with a change of years in R?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

| week | year | politicalization_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 52 | 2020 | 5 |
| 53 | 2020 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021 | 4 |
| 3 | 2021 | 11 |

For this data frame, I want to plot the course of `politicalization_sum` chronologically. I tried the following:

```
per_week <- per_week %>%
  arrange(desc(week))

ggplot(per_week, mapping = aes(x = week, y = politicalization_sum)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

With this, the x-axis starts at week 0 and goes to week 53, with a large gap in the middle. What can I do to have the x-axis start at week 52 in 2020 and end at week 3 in 2021?

Comment: Start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470414/convert-week-number-to-date and convert the year and week to a date.  Then plot

Comment: If you are looking to include an axis break in your plot you could look at `ggbreak` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
per_week %>% 
  mutate(x = make_date(year)) %>% 
  mutate(date = x + lubridate::weeks(week-1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, politicalization_sum)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y (%b)")+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly like this, thank you!