# Convert Year/Week to Timestamp (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: r, date, timestamp

I've got a Dataset that looks like this:

| Year | Week | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 1 | 2 |
| 2010 | 4 | 3 |
| 2010 | 5 | 5 |
| 2010 | 6 | 1 |

I would like to convert the Year-Week columns into a single timestamp column (dd/mm/yyyy). Day of the week could be the first or the last one.
Is there a simple way to solve this?

Best,
Daniel

Comment: Checking this thread might get you there: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470414/convert-week-number-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weeks function in lubridate and str_c function in stringr might provide it:

```
df <- tribble(~year, ~week, 2010,1,2010,4,2010,5,2010,6)

df_tbl <- df %>% 
  mutate(beg = ymd(str_c(year, "-01-01")),
         date_var = beg + weeks(week))

df_tbl$date_var
```

Comment: This works. Note that `stringr::str_c()` could just as easily be replaced with `base::paste()`

Comment: `weeks()` and `ymd()` are both part of the `lubridate` package, which could be clearer in the example. This code will `require(lubridate)` and `require(dplyr)` to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you count week 1 as starting on 1st January, you could do:

```r
as.Date(paste(df$Year, 1, 1, sep = '-')) + 7 * (df$Week - 1)
#> [1] "2010-01-01" "2010-01-22" "2010-01-29" "2010-02-05"
```

If you count week 1 as starting on the first Monday of the year (as per ISO 8601) then you could use this little function:

```r
year_week <- function(year, week) {
  as.Date(unlist((Map(function(y, w) {
    d <- which(lubridate::wday(as.Date(paste(y, 1, 1:7, sep = '-'))) == 2)
    as.Date(paste(y, 1, d, sep = '-')) + (w - 1) * 7}, y = year, w = week))),
    origin = '1970-01-01')
}
```

This will give you the date of the *nth* Monday in the year, so that we have:

```r
year_week(df$Year, df$Week)
#> [1] "2010-01-04" "2010-01-25" "2010-02-01" "2010-02-08"
```