# Replace week number on x axis with month in ggplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, lubridate

The below code makes the below plot

```
library(tibble); library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)

structure(c(1286150400, 1412899200, 1508025600, 1257465600, 1276214400, 
1285545600, 1669248000, 1255478400, 818035200, 1695945600, 1698624000, 
716083200, 602812800, 814924800, 1570492800, -175478400, 1571356800, 
1695686400, 1698364800, 1051747200, 1065571200, 499046400, 427766400, 
1382572800, 1602115200, 1162425600, 1349481600, 423878400, 530323200, 
1349481600, 1390694400, 1633132800, 1634515200, 1475020800, 183859200, 
1633132800, 1352937600, 321494400, -355017600, 1698364800, 1478304000, 
-355190400, 1556236800, -69984000, 1382227200, -473126400, 404956800, 
1539648000, 1496275200, 1570838400, 250387200, 1697673600, 814320000, 
687139200, -2151100800, 813024000, 1072915200, 1476921600, -83548800, 
1697500800, 1632528000, 1600732800, 1286755200, 939513600, 1698192000, 
1539907200, 1606435200, 1507766400, 814147200, 813024000, 1570838400, 
1274832000, 1381276800, 685756800, 497664000, 750124800, 66700800, 
1695859200, 1508284800, 1698192000, 1316736000, 1633305600, 1001980800, 
497923200, 1507680000, 1286409600, 814147200, 564624000, 1445299200, 
1508976000, 497318400, -51840000, 1508025600, 1286928000, 529286400, 
1319068800, 1695254400, 1695427200, 1698192000, 765936000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")) -> date

tibble(date) %>% 
  mutate(week = week(date)) %>% 
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(week, n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

I need the data split into weeks, but I need the x axis to be labelled with the month rather than week number. In below, I have drawn in red what I need the x axis to look like. Can I achieve this with code in ggplot?

[image]

Comment: The same day-month will fall on slightly different weeks over the years, introducing error on your data. For example, today's week (2024-03-18) was eight times 11 and two times 12 over the last ten years. @stefan's solution bypass this setting the same year for all dates, but the error remains. This is relevant if you want a `scale_x_date` plot.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert the week number to dates (with a fixed year) following e.g. [Convert week number to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470414/convert-week-number-to-date).  Doing so allows to easily add the month name as the x axis label using `scale_x_date`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(lubridate)

tibble(date) |>
  mutate(
    week = week(date),
    week = as.Date(
      paste(2023, week, 1, sep = "-"), "%Y-%U-%u"
    )
  ) |>
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(week, n)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(
    date_labels = "%b",
    date_breaks = "1 month"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have lines on x axis (as per red lines in my drawing above) showing cut off between months?