How to deal with 53 weeks in r and add a few more?
I have a vector of dates in the following format: YYWW. For example 0951 is year 2009 and week 51 of that year and so on.
What I want is to keep this format and create a new variable that has + 7 weeks from the initial dates. The problem is also that 2009 and 2015 have 53 weeks but 2010 has only 52 weeks. How to to also take care of that effectively?
library("dplyr")
# Create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(date = c("0951", "0952", "1001", "1551"))

df_1 <- df %>%
mutate(get_date = as.Date(paste0(substr(date, 1,2), "-W", substr(date, 3, 4), "-1"), format = "%y-W%U-%u"))

I have tried to convert first the initial format of the week into something I could manipulate and then add 7 weeks on this new variable but for example for 0951 observation when I run the above code it returns next week (i.e. week 52 of 2009) which is wrong but for the "1001" it returns the correct date.
Could someone please help?
Thanks,

does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46183403?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object

First you need to understand that you don't actually have dates. Then you need to consider carefully how you intend to deal with the fact that 365 and 366 are not multiples of 7.

To use the ISO-8601 definition you should use ISOweek::ISOweek2date (note: this needs the year with the leading century to function properly -- I use an ifelse statement here just to make it work, but there are better methods)
library("dplyr")
library("ISOweek")

df <- data.frame(date = c("0951", "0952", "1001", "1551"))

df_1 <- df %>% mutate(week = substr(date, 3, 4))%>% 
  mutate(year = ifelse(substr(date, 1, 2) > 40, paste0("19", substr(date, 1, 2) ), paste0("20", substr(date, 1, 2) ) ) ) %>% 
  mutate(date1 = paste0(year, "-W", week, "-1")) %>% 
  mutate(date_final = ISOweek2date(date1))



Thank you very much Laura :) It solved my problem. And thanks for taking the time!
